# How to change the MiniController button if is live streaming

Tags: android, casting, chromecast

I need to show a play/stop toggle instead of a play/pause button when we are casting live content to the chromecast, but we still need the play/pause when casting other videos.

I set the minicontroller casting buttons to a custom button where in the onResume I called my function that bound different drawables depending on what is being casted. The problem is that when I change the video to live (or other way around) on a page with a already showing minicontroller it doens`t call onResume again (rightfully so), and it keeps the same buttons. I don't know if there is another event inside minicontroller that I can use.  I try to use SessionManagerListener and a UiController to bound my functions to certain events but both of them there were problems (I probably did something wrong, dont know).

My function is:

```
fun checkButton() {
    activity?.let {
        val mCastContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(activity!!.baseContext)
        val mCastSession = mCastContext.sessionManager.currentCastSession

        if (mCastSession?.remoteMediaClient?.currentItem != null) {
            val drawablePlay = ContextCompat.getDrawable(it, R.drawable.cast_ic_mini_controller_play)
            val drawableStop = ContextCompat.getDrawable(it, R.drawable.cast_ic_mini_controller_stop)

            uiMediaController.bindImageViewToPlayPauseToggle(button, drawablePlay!!, drawableStop!!, drawableStop, ProgressBar(it), false)
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to call my function every time the miniController loads or something like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it... looks like uiMediaController.bindImageViewToPlayPauseToggle already do this automatically, it already has the logic to use the stop button when is live streaming...